# My tests were running and then I clicked "Run as --> Maven clean" and now when I click "Run as --> Maven test" it doesn't work anymore

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, cucumber

My project worked after right-clicking on the pom.xml file in Eclipse and selecting: "Run as --> Maven install" and then "Run as --> Maven test".

I started experimenting around and selected: "Run as --> Maven clean" and then "Run as --> Maven install". This time around I got build errors and couldn't run "Run as --> Maven test". What happened? Why did I get build errors?

I can get the tests to work again if I exit out of Eclipse, delete everything in the .m2 folder, relaunch Eclipse, and click "Run as --> Maven install" twice (the first time produces an error, the second time does the trick). I have no clue as to why this works. I'm confused about what "Maven clean", "Maven install", and "Maven test" do. Yes, I've read the [documentation on maven.apache.org](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) but I'm still confused.

Here's my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.ah</groupId>
  <artifactId>goToLinks</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>GoToLinks</name>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- cucumber-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <parallel>methods</parallel>
                    <useUnlimitedThreads>true</useUnlimitedThreads>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Here's the error I'm getting:

> ```
> [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
> [ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
> [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
> [ERROR] Source option 5 is no longer supported. Use 7 or later.
> [ERROR] Target option 5 is no longer supported. Use 7 or later.
> [INFO] 2 errors 
> [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
> [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
> [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> [INFO] Total time:  1.540 s
> [INFO] Finished at: 2020-06-01T19:47:03-04:00
> [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> ```

Comment: Which JDK version do you have?

Comment: The error is simply saying that the JDK  compiler version is set to 5 and it must be greater than jdk 6

Comment: @UnknownBeast I'm using the default for Maven projects: J2SE 1.5. How do I change it?

Comment: Right Click on JRE System Library -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path -> In the Libraries tab click on JRE System Library -> click on edit button (right side) -> Check the Alternate JRE and then click on Installed JRE button ->  Click on add button and then click on directory button and then select the JDK home directory containing the bin and other folders

Comment: Before that make sure that you have installed JDK in your system and not JRE

Comment: @UnknownBeast Followed your directions and using JDK 13.0.1 now. Right-clicked on the pom file and clicked "Run as --> Maven clean" and then "Run as --> Maven Test" and still getting the same error

Comment: What is it showing in JRE System Library in your project?

Comment: @UnknownBeast I'm running JRE System Library [JDK-13.0.1]. Here's a screenshot of my project from Eclipse: https://i.imgur.com/DzxrrVW.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maven compiler plugin defaults to Java 1.5 but the version of the JDK you use no longer supports that. You can resolve that by configuring the compiler plugin to use a different version of java.

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html

```
    <project>
      [...]
      <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
      </properties>
      [...]
    </project>
```

or configure the plugin directly:

```
    <project>
      [...]
      <build>
        [...]
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
              <source>1.8</source>
              <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
        [...]
      </build>
      [...]
    </project>
```